# Using any Google API

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-photos

Without doubt this is easy question. In fact, so obvious that I cannot find straight forward answer:

**What is the simplest way to use API for some Google's products, e.g. maps or photos?**

I'm interested in the simplest options, like determining country based on coordinates or downloading first image from album with specified name.

It seems in order to use their products I need to have Client Id, which I understand means that one needs to be registered and pay fees. Is there really no option to simply try it out without paying?

Edit:
Following [example code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse) suggested in comments click on YOUR_API_KEY and this will transfer you to page when you can get API key.

Comment: Google also provide free api

Comment: @chiragshah how to use it? I might be too stupid, but honestly I don't understand how to activate/use one. Would greatly appreciate any link to documentation or tutorial, or hints what to look for.

Comment: The Google Maps API is free as long as you are using their free request per day. You can check it [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?csw=1#usagelimits). Now, for your concern about determining country based on coordinates, then you can use the [Reverse Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding). The term geocoding generally refers to translating a human-readable address into a location on a map. The process of doing the converse, translating a location on the map into a human-readable address, is known as reverse geocoding.

Comment: Here is the [sample code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse) for it.

Comment: @KENdi Thanks! It seems that due to my low internet speed I was never actually transferred to places where I can obtain keys. With your links clearly stating how one can get those, I've kept on forcing my way and now I'm there. Sometimes cafes are not good.